# How to insert markdown code in MongoDB with Go backend and ReactJS frontend

Tags: json, reactjs, mongodb, go, markdown

I want to insert Markdown code in MongoDB. I am not sure what is the best approach for this problem. My configuration is as follows

- Frontend : ReactJS
- Backend : Go
- Database : MongoDB

Right now I am inserting data in JSON format. Frontend sends JSON which Backend saves to MongoDB. Now I want to insert a raw Markdown which frontend will send to backend, and save it as **String**.
To render, backend will send this JSON back to frontend, and that will be displayed using Markdown previewer.

Here is my current JSON

```json
{
        "questions": "First Economics question",
        "marks": "3",
        "options": [
            {
                "option": "Economics option 1 for student",
                "correct": false
            },
            {
                "option": "Economics option 2 for student",
                "correct": false
            },
            {
                "option": "Economics option 3 for student",
                "correct": true
            },
            {
                "option": "Economics option 4 for student",
                "correct": false
            }
        ]
}
```

Now I want to store markdown in `question` json field like so

````json
{
    "questions": 
    "    
    | First Header  | Second Header |
    | ------------- | ------------- |
    | Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
    | Content Cell  | Content Cell  |

    ```
    let message = \'Hello world\';
    alert(message);
    ```     
    ",
        "marks": "3",
        "options": [
            {
                "option": "Economics option 1 for student",
                "correct": false
            },
            {
                "option": "Economics option 2 for student",
                "correct": false
            },
            {
                "option": "Economics option 3 for student",
                "correct": true
            },
            {
                "option": "Economics option 4 for student",
                "correct": false
            }
        ]
}
````

Actual problem is when I am trying to use `single quote(')` and `double quote (")`, I can't use that. As you can see that I have added slash **[ \ ]** with ***Hello world*** in the JSON above. Also, I feel difficulty in storing complex Markdown script having different styles like bullets points + code scripts, especial character etc...

Here are my questions:

- Is my current approach correct ?
- If not, then what is the correct approach ?

Comment: What is your go code for storing them? There should  not be any problem at all.

Comment: Hi Qiaosen, I have a go struct which is populated when data is received at the backend and that struct is saved to MongoDB as document. As I have defined in my question, the problem is **quotations [ ' and " ]**, and also especial characters. Also I can't store LaTeX code. I have to first transform it with appending slashes using **[ \ ]** which I don't want to to. Have you tried to store something like this before ??

Comment: All JSON encoders escape quotes and other special characters if necessary. If you have problems with that you're hand-crafting your JSON documents. Don't do that. Use the encoders provided by JavaScript and Go.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I feel like this is frontend work and it will send the escaped JSON to backend. That escaped string with Markdown code will simply be stored by Go backend to MongoDB, I guess.  Is my understanding correct ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved my problem and would like to share the solution.
I faced 2 issues but in my above question I only asked about 1 issue, because I wanted to resolve that on priority.

**Issue-1:** As described in my question above
**Issue-2:** I was giving multi-line Markdown code as JSON value in Postman which postman was not recognizing.

**Solution**
The solution to the first problem was to append the escape characters `\n , \\` to the string.
Solution to the second issue was to write the whole string in one line so Postman could recognize this as a valid markdown JSON value.

Both the problems were resolved using **[Hjson tool](https://hjson.github.io/try.html)**. This tool converted my markdown multi-line value into a single line and also added required escape characters.

- Multi-line string to Hjson with complex Markdown code including LaTeX and Hjson generated the single line value to the right-hand side panel.
  [image]
- Here is the single line value to Postman
  [image]

Thanks to **Peter** and **Qiaosen Huang** for their helpful comments.